# Spring throwing error after SAML cert update

Tags: saml, spring-saml

I have a perfectly working Spring Security web application that uses SAML SSO. The client (IdP) changed their certs.  I updated the cert and the CA certs to my keystore.jks. I am getting redirected properly to the IdP,  I log in and get properly redirected back to my app.  At that point I am getting theses in the logs:

```
Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential (validate) (SignatureValidator.java:54)
Creating XMLSignature object (buildSignature) (SignatureValidator.java:90)
Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1 (validate) (SignatureValidator.java:64)
Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl' (validate) (SignatureValidator.java:65)
Signature validated with key from supplied credential (validate) (SignatureValidator.java:70)
SSL negotiation with xxxxxx using candidate credential was successful (verifySignature) (BaseSignatureTrustEngine.java:148)
Successfully verifiServer certificate verify failed: signer not foundidate) (BaseSignatureTrustEngine.java:101)
Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential (validateConnected to HTTPS on 34.196.133.252)
Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key (validate) (ExplicitKeyTrustEvaluator.java:95
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
```

So it looks like something is being validated, but I do not understand why it's failing.  I double checked with keytool and all the CA's are there.

Comment: You might have to update the IDP meta-data  as well to reflect the correct certificate that is used for signing.

Comment: @mmaceachran Could you provide the whole KeyInfo element of the SAMLResponse?